# WPF- datagrid row validation errors to a textblock/label?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml, datagrid

In WPF i have a `DataDrid` with different validations.

So far i used `ToolTip` in the `DataGrid` to show the error validation:

```
<DataGrid.RowValidationErrorTemplate>
   <ControlTemplate>
      <Grid Margin="0,-2,0,-2" ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}},Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">
         <Ellipse StrokeThickness="0" Fill="Red" Width="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" Height="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" />
         <TextBlock Text="!" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
      </Grid>
   </ControlTemplate>
</DataGrid.RowValidationErrorTemplate>
```

Now the client asked to show the validation error in a different `TextBlock/Label` in the page- how do i do that? How do i use the: `(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent` outside the `DataGrid`?

Comment: by first stating that this will cost him an additional day because the requirement wasn't in scope :) secondly, since you already have a validation, you need to capture the input (event) and validate it right there. No more XAML validation, but behind-code validation.

Comment: @Schuere and how do i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a list (e.g. `MyList`) as your `DataGrid.ItemsSource` which is an `ObservableCollection<ItemVM>` where `ItemVM` represents the view-model of each `DataGridRow` then You can use a `MultiBinding` with a multi-value converter to save the last error message in a property of currently invalid `ItemVM` (e.g. `ErrorMessage`) and then retrieve it in your desired `TextBlock.Text` through binding.

You can say this is a trick for 3-way binding where `TextBlock.Text` and `CurrentItem.ErrorMessage` and `(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent` are all bound together.

The following codes will clear things up:

In MainWindow:

```
public ObservableCollection<ItemVM> MyList { get; set; }
public ItemVM CurrentItem { get; set; }
```

In ItemVM:

```
public class ItemVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //implementation of INotifyPropertyChanged ...

    string _errorMessage;
    public string ErrorMessage
    {
        get
        {
            return _errorMessage;
        }
        set
        {
            _errorMessage = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ErrorMessage");
        }
    }
    // Other Properties ...
}
```

In Xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:MultiConverter x:Key="multiConv"/>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding MyList}" >
        <DataGrid.RowValidationErrorTemplate>
            <ControlTemplate >
                <Grid Margin="0,-2,0,-2">
                    <Ellipse StrokeThickness="0" Fill="Red" Width="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" Height="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="!" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <Grid.ToolTip>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource multiConv}">
                            <Binding Path="(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                AncestorType=DataGridRow}"/>
                            <Binding Path="DataContext.CurrentItem" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                AncestorType=Window}"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Grid.ToolTip>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowValidationErrorTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding CurrentItem.ErrorMessage}"/>
</Grid>
```

And finally in MultiValueConverter:

```
public class MultiConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
        object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ((ItemVM)values[1]).ErrorMessage = values[0].ToString();
        return values[0].ToString();
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(
        object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

---

**EDIT**

> my DataGrid.ItemsSource is DataSet DefaultView- its DB based

Ok, since you are using `DataSet.DefaultView` as the `ItemsSource` do it like this:

**1)** First define a very small simple class that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`to wrap your error message:

```
public class ErrorContainer: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    string _message;
    public string Message
    {
        get
        {return _message;}
        set
        {_message = value; OnPropertyChanged("Message");}
    }
}
```

**2)** Then use an instance of this class as a property in your `MainWindow`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

....

    public ErrorContainer Error { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;

        // initialize ErrorContainer
        Error = new ErrorContainer();

        // some dummy test data (you're probably getting your data from DB instead)
        DataSet ds = new DataSet("MyDataSet");
        DataTable dt = new DataTable("MyDataTable");

        DataColumn propertyName = new DataColumn("Property");
        DataColumn propertyValue = new DataColumn("Value");
        DataColumn propertyDate = new DataColumn("Date", typeof(DateTime));

        dt.Columns.Add(propertyName);
        dt.Columns.Add(propertyValue);
        dt.Columns.Add(propertyDate);

        dt.Rows.Add("Name1", 1, DateTime.Now);
        dt.Rows.Add("Name2", 2, DateTime.Now);
        dt.Rows.Add("Name3", 3, DateTime.Now);

        ds.Tables.Add(dt);

        // bind DataGrid.ItemsSource (do NOT set this again in xaml)
        var srcBinding = new Binding();
        srcBinding.Source = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        myDataGrid.SetBinding(DataGrid.ItemsSourceProperty, srcBinding);

    }
}
```

**3)** Now change the second path in the multi-binding to `DataContext.Error` and also change `TextBox.Text` binding to `Error.Message`:

```
<Grid>
     <DataGrid x:Name=x:Name="myDataGrid">
    ....

                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource multiConv}">
                            <Binding Path="(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                AncestorType=DataGridRow}"/>
                            <Binding Path="DataContext.Error" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                AncestorType=Window}"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Grid.ToolTip>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowValidationErrorTemplate>
    </DataGrid>
    <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding Error.Message}"/>
</Grid>
```

**4)** And finally change your `MultiValueConverter.Convert` method to this:

```
    public object Convert(
        object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ((ErrorContainer)values[1]).Message = values[0].ToString();
        return values[0].ToString();
    }
```

Comment: the problem is that its a small project so i didnt write it in mvvm

Comment: It doesn't necessarily have to be mvvm, you only need to have an `ObservableCollection` as your `DataGrid.ItemsSource` and a class representing each `DataGridRow` that implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`. That's all. Looking at your code, You've already used a binding to `MyValue`. Which class this property belongs to? and what is your  `DataGrid.ItemsSource`?

Comment: my DataGrid.ItemsSource is DataSet DefaultView- its DB based

Comment: Can you update you question and provide more details (full datagrid xaml and relevant code behind)?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a class like ValidationRules that holds a Validate Function.

due to the magnificent binding that occurs, you no longer need to follow the validation as it is binded. This however sticks to the control.

You can also create an event on the control inside the datagrid that is being used to validate.

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="MyValue">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Textbox Text="{Binding MyValue}" OnLeave="tb_OnLeave"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

In you behind you can then have something like:

```
private void tb_OnLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //sender defines your value;
  Textbox s = (Textbox)sender;

  //validate the Text property of the sender
  if(ValidationRule.ValidateTextBox(s.Text)); //true
  return;

  //set the focus on your control
  s.Focus(); 

  //set the text of your other control
  YourOtherControl.Text = string.Format("The value of textbox: {0} is not valid", s.Text);
}
```

The point here is that you will not use the validationBinding anymore. 
I think there are ways to do it via binding but i'm not strong enough on that topic to give you a better answer.

Perhaps the **RelativeSource** can be used to point to another control. But as I said, I don't know enough to be sure.